# Field not found: pixelToWorld (com.uwsoft.editor.renderer.data.ProjectInfoVO)

Tags: java, libgdx, overlap2d

I got this error when compile desktop application:

```
Exception in thread “LWJGL Application” com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Field not found: pixelToWorld (com.uwsoft.editor.renderer.data.ProjectInfoVO)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readFields(Json.java:776)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:902)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:714)
at com.uwsoft.editor.renderer.resources.ResourceManager.loadProjectVO(ResourceManager.java:334)
at com.uwsoft.editor.renderer.resources.ResourceManager.initAllResources(ResourceManager.java:86)
at com.uwsoft.editor.renderer.Overlap2DStage.initSceneLoader(Overlap2DStage.java:92)
at com.mygdx.Test.GameStage.<init>(GameStage.java:9)
at com.mygdx.Test.TestGame.create(TestGame.java:15)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:143)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
```

I have check my project.dt and I found field ‘pixelToWorld’. Why is this happen?
Here to view my project.dt: http://pastebin.com/FqnVkw8p

---

UPDATE:

I follow this tutorial: [making-physics-based-side-scroller-project-setup-part-1](http://overlap2d.com/making-physics-based-side-scroller-project-setup-part-1/)

I only have 2 class in my core project. `GameStage.java` and `TestGame.java`

`GameStage.java`

```
package com.mygdx.Test;

import com.uwsoft.editor.renderer.Overlap2DStage;

public class GameStage extends Overlap2DStage{
    public GameStage() {

        // This will create SceneLoader instance and configure all things like default resource manager, physics e.t.c
        initSceneLoader();

        // This will load MainScene data from json and make Actors from it
        sceneLoader.loadScene("MainScene");

        // Get the root actor and add it to stage
        addActor(sceneLoader.getRoot());
    }
}
```

---

`TestGame.java`

```
package com.mygdx.Test;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class TestGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

    private GameStage stage;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        stage = new GameStage();
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act();
        stage.draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: paste please the code of class that you are trying to deserialize json to. When you are doing something like **T t = json...** I ask you about **T** class code

Comment: @m.antkowicz I didn't do that. I update my question description. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking into sources you can [find here](https://github.com/UnderwaterApps/overlap2d-runtime-libgdx/tree/master/src/com/uwsoft/editor/renderer) and what I've found is that the **sceneLoader.loadScene()** method returns the object with **Scene** that is being kept in HashMap with **.dt** (I guess it is something like .json) file name.

The thing is that method **loadScene()** is looking for a **pixelToWorld** field but there is no pixelToWorld in **MainScene.dt**

I guess you should call sceneLoader.loadScene("project"); or you have done something wrong with MainScene.dt and this is why there is no pixelToWorld

Comment: I can find 'MainScene.dt' inside assets/scenes/MainScene.dt and also project.dt inside assets/. So, I have both of the. I tried change 'project.dt' to 'MainScene.dt' and got this error 'File not found: project.dt (Internal)'. It can't be, because overlap2D default is load 'project.dt' for root of exported overlap2d project.

Comment: then what dou you have in you MainScene.dt? is a **pixelToWorld** also there?

Comment: Yes, I didn't find 'pixelToWorld', but this asset exported directly from overlap2D app. Is this bug or something? Or Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: as I wrote above you are calling **sceneLoader.loadScene("MainScene");** so the method is tryng to find **pixelToWorld** in  **MainScene.dt**. I'm not sure what you should to because I don't know overlap2d, but for sure here is your problem and I guess you should call sceneLoader.loadScene("project"); **or** you have done something wrong with MainScene.dt and this is why there is no **pixelToWorld**

Comment: Please add your answer that methos trying to read 'pixelToWorld' that isn't in 'MainScene.dt'. I'll mark it as answer. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using the latest version of the Overlap IDE, but a too early version of the runtime.
Try upgrading your runtime to 1.1 and try again, although you will probably have to use sceneloader